# Cloud Native Buildpack - Getting Packages or Buildpacks From the nexus repo using URI in the builder.toml

Tags: buildpack

getting below error

```
Downloading from http://<serverIP>/repository/deepak- releases/deepak-java/deepak-java/deepak-java/deepak-java-deepak-java.tgz 
1.53 MB/1.53 MB 
ERROR: failed to add buildpacks to builder: downloading buildpack: extracting from 
http://<serverIP>/repository/deepak-releases/deepak-java/deepak-java/deepak-java/deepak-java-deepak-java.tgz: 
reading buildpack: reading buildpack.toml: could not find entry path 'buildpack.toml':not exist
```

'Currently am trying to take buildpacks which are located in the nexus repo, using the uri option present under buildpacks in the builder.toml. Previously i have tried to use the image and path which are in the local now trying to use url.

- Took a buildpack and uploaded it to Nexus repo in the .tgz format.
- tried to call the path of the files in the URI session of the builder.toml

mention as below in the buildpack session of the builder.toml'

---

```
<builder.toml- configuration file>

[[buildpacks]]
  uri = "http://serverIP/repository/deepak-nexus-repo/deepak-epo/buildpacks/javarepo/buildpacks-java.tar.gz"


[[order]]

 [[order.group]]
   id = "paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates"
   optional = true
   version = "3.6.3"
```

---

'Expecting

- trying to get the packages from the nexus repo and include those while building the image
- generally if we mention the image in the uri session of the buildpacks in **builder.toml** file as above. It will take all the required packages or buildpacks from the image and will use it for the building of the image.
- so now i took the buildpacks converted to .tgz format as per the official doc -https://buildpacks.io/docs/app-developer-guide/specify-buildpacks/
- uploaded this compressed buildpack in the nexus repo and now calling this url/path of the file in the builder.toml'

Comment: Hello! Have you tried locally building your buildpack then pushing it as an OCI image to your image registry (Nexus 3 supports OCI registries).
I am not sure how you packaged in a .tar.gz archive, also I'm not even sure you can consume remote .tar.gz buildpacks.
I have gathered some notes recently on how to create and publish a cloud native buildpack: https://blog.paketo.io/posts/manually-testing-changes-to-paketo-buildpacks/ .
Let me know if that helps!